# App crashes when I deselect an item in a UICollectionView

Tags: swift, ios8, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm working on UICollectionView. I'm assigning one image to collection view cell when user selects it, and changing the image when user selects other cell, as shown in below code

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    let selectedCell : CollectionCellForAlertView = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CollectionCellForAlertView
    println("cell selected")
    selectedCell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "someImage.png")

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    println("deselected")
    let deselectedCell : CollectionCellForAlertView = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CollectionCellForAlertView
    deselectedCell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "someOtherImage.png")

}
```

Sometimes it works properly but some other times it crashes because 'deselectedCell' will have nil value. Can anybody please tel me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you. I tested it in my app and it worked.

```
     let deselectedCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as CollectionCellForAlertView
        deselectedCell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "someOtherImage.png")
```

Comment: No its not working.. As I said, sometimes it will work fine some other time it crashes. I have around 15 items in my collection view. As I scroll down and  keep selecting and deselecting, at some point of time it crashes.

Comment: can you upload your project to github, so I can have a look.